# Multiple D3js graphs on one view cause performance issues when using responsive disign

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive

I have about 20 charts on one single view, everything performs perfectly until I try to attemp to implement graphs inside the responsive design. Each graph have a separate ID.

I am using Angular directives to create those graphs.

this piece of code is the troublemaker:

```
var the_chart = $("#"+attrs.id+"chart"),
                aspect = the_chart.attr("width") / the_chart.attr("height"),
                container = element.parent();

                $(window).on("resize", function() {

                    var targetWidth = container.width();
                    the_chart.attr("width", targetWidth);           
                    var value = Math.round(targetWidth / aspect);
                    the_chart.attr("height",value);
                }).trigger("resize");
```

Problem is that I call a directive x amount of times and in every directive I call the piece of code above. It will perform fine for 1 or 2 graphs, but the more graphs you have, the more performance issues .trigger("resize") will cause because more and more  graphs has to be re-rendered because of multiple instances of $(window).on("resize"... is created.

I am forced to trigger resize because width of container is not set until whole view is rendered.

Comment: Does it help to debounce the resize event, e.g. with underscore/lodash [_.debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce)?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. When composing form with thirty other subforms (selected by various conditions) my code started to run very slowly. It did not help nh-show/ng-hide. I was confused. Directive ng-if solved my problem.

You should create structure like this:

```
<div ng-if="...."> ... </div>
<div ng-if="...."> ... </div>
<div ng-if="...."> ... </div>
...
```

NOT THIS:

```
<div>....</div>
<div>....</div>
<div>....</div>
```